# "One or more scopes are not compatible with each other" error when retrieving access token for the

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I have an app that integrated with Outlook, Calendar via the Azure AD REST API v.2. I have tried to use the incremental and dynamic scopes to "upgrade" the user's token so that the app can access OneDrive as well, (so the user could directly upload her email attachments in her cloud).
The authorization code retrieval redirects went well and the user is asked for the additional scope after login (files.readwrite). However, on step 2 when I try to obtain the access token I get the following error:

```
System.Exception: Acquire token by authorization code returned BadRequest: 

{
  "error": "invalid_scope",
  "error_description": "AADSTS70011: The provided value for the input parameter 'scope' is not valid. One or more scopes in 'https://outlook.office.com/mail.readwrite https://outlook.office.com/mail.send https://outlook.office.com/contacts.readwrite https://outlook.office.com/calendars.readwrite https://outlook.office.com/people.read files.readwrite' are not compatible with each other.\\r\\nTrace ID: b02fa0bf-6e86-4156-81e8-294dbc851500\\r\\nCorrelation ID: 3697bd18-554c-47e6-81cc-de3c47780fc9\\r\\nTimestamp: 2018-02-01 15:26:10Z",
  "error_codes": [
    70011
  ],
  "timestamp": "2018-02-01 15:26:10Z",
  "trace_id": "b02fa0bf-6e86-4156-81e8-294dbc851500",
  "correlation_id": "3697bd18-554c-47e6-81cc-de3c47780fc9"
}
```

Or this error:

```
System.Exception: Acquire token by authorization code returned BadRequest: 
{
  "error": "invalid_request",
  "error_description": "AADSTS700022: The provided value for the input parameter scope is not valid because it contains more than one resource. The scope https://outlook.office.com/mail.readwrite https://outlook.office.com/mail.send https://outlook.office.com/contacts.readwrite https://outlook.office.com/calendars.readwrite https://outlook.office.com/people.read files.readwrite is not valid.\\r\\nTrace ID: 9781d206-11b3-46c8-b972-8c4e77641c00\\r\\nCorrelation ID: 7e63af89-6e95-45f4-abaa-8f32051fb9ef\\r\\nTimestamp: 2018-02-01 15:36:32Z",
  "error_codes": [
    700022
  ],
  "timestamp": "2018-02-01 15:36:32Z",
  "trace_id": "9781d206-11b3-46c8-b972-8c4e77641c00",
  "correlation_id": "7e63af89-6e95-45f4-abaa-8f32051fb9ef"
}
```

I assume I can't use the same token for both Outlook and OneDrive access because they are "different resources", one being part of the Office 365 and the other in Microsoft graph, however, I struggle to find a comprehensive list of which resources are compatible with which in here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-scopes).

My question is, does this mean that I will need to maintain 2 different tokens (my app uses the offline scope to refresh the token) for OneDrive and Outlook?

Also is there a difference between OneDrive for a personal account and OneDrive for a business accounts (which I think is the same as Sharepoint)? When working with outlook I can use the same code for outlook.com and Office365 emails, but I am not sure this is the case when it comes to working with files.

With the Google APIs it's quite simple to just add the Google Drive (or any other API) scope to your Gmail access scopes, but I guess that's not the case with the Microsoft APIs.

Thanks

Comment: You do need two tokens for sure. The problem is that each API is allowed to define their permission scopes and roles freely, so they can also overlap. And a token always has an audience claim, which says for which API it is meant for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you will need two tokens. As juunas said in his comment, the problem is the audience, or the `aud` parameter in the token. You're asking for scopes that apply to two different audiences: `https://outlook.office.com` and `https://graph.microsoft.com`.

The good news is that these two APIs do have overlapping scopes, and Azure AD will allow you to use a refresh token issued for Graph to get a token for the Outlook API. So here's what I suggest (assuming you're doing [authorization code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-code))

1. Do your authorization request using Graph scopes:

   ```
   mail.readwrite 
   mail.send 
   contacts.readwrite 
   calendars.readwrite 
   people.read 
   files.readwrite
   ```
2. Do a token request with `grant_type=authorization_code` using those same Graph scopes. This gets your Graph token + refresh token.
3. Do a token request with `grant_type=refresh_token` using the refresh token from previous step, but this time with ONLY the Outlook-applicable scopes, qualified for `https://outlook.office.com`. This gets your Outlook token.

   ```
   https://outlook.office.com/mail.readwrite 
   https://outlook.office.com/mail.send 
   https://outlook.office.com/contacts.readwrite 
   https://outlook.office.com/calendars.readwrite 
   https://outlook.office.com/people.read
   ```

Comment: is this token refresh thing applied to SharePoint rest api also  ?

Comment: @Jason Johnston Now they are not exposing refresh token. So how to get token for Sharepoint?