# How to get an access token for IMAP an Outlook contacts?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I would like to access my Microsoft Outlook Mailbox with my own app. For this, I want to use IMAP for mails and Microsoft Graph for contacts.

For this, I try to acquire an access token with the scopes

`offline_access profile openid email Contacts.Read Contacts.Read.Shared https://outlook.office.com/IMAP.AccessAsUser.All https://outlook.office.com/SMTP.Send`

and send the request to

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token`.

The answer is a HTTP `400 BadRequest` with the following message:

Error:

*invalid_scope*

Description:

*Error:"invalid_scope", Description:"AADSTS70011: The provided value for the input parameter 'scope' is not valid. One or more scopes in 'offline_access profile openid email Contacts.Read Contacts.Read.Shared https://outlook.office.com/IMAP.AccessAsUser.All [https://outlook.office.com/SMTP.Send'](https://outlook.office.com/SMTP.Send%27) are not compatible with each other. Trace ID: ac5d234c-b69d-426a-afd9-209387383a00 Correlation ID: 9203e61a-ecc5-4dfb-a9e4-e31135a6de47 Timestamp: 2023-11-16 11:20:02Z", Uri:""*

Why can I not get one access token for IMAP an for Graph together?

I wonder about this, this I got an autorization code as well, and I got an email with the note, that my app granted to this scopes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Note** that: You cannot generate access token for different Azure resources at once. You need to generate multiple access tokens for multiple resources.

- It is not possible to have multiple API audiences in one single token.
- You need to obtain separate access tokens for different types of APIs that is one access token for Microsoft Graph and one for Microsoft Outlook.

As you want to access mails and contacts, you can make use of **Microsoft Graph API** by generating API permissions like below:

[image]

Now generate the **auth code**:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize? 
client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code  
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query  
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default offline_access openid
&state=12345
```

[image]

Generated **access token** by using below parameters:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default offline_access openid
grant_type:authorization_code
code:code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
client_secret:ClientSecret
```

[image]

When I decoded the access token, the scopes are present:

[image]

By using the above access token, you can access mail and contacts. ***If still the issue persists***, generate two different tokens for Microsoft Graph and one for Microsoft Outlook.

**Reference:**

["One or more scopes are not compatible with each other" error when retrieving access token for the](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48579143/one-or-more-scopes-are-not-compatible-with-each-other-error-when-retrieving-ac) by Jason Johnston